# A quotient group over a commutator of a normal subgroup is in the center.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $H \triangleleft G$  is a normal subgroup, $K = [G, H]$ is ф commutator subgroup. Then K is the smallest normal subgroup such that $H/K \leqslant Z(G/K)$, where Z(G/K) is the center of G/K.

Since $K \geqslant H'$ then $K \triangleleft H$ and $H/K$ is an abelian group. But why does it commute with other elements of $G/K$? If I realize that, I think I will prove its smallness.

Comment: This follows immediately from the definition of $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$gKhK = ghK = [g, h]hgK = [g, h]KhKgK = hKgK$

since $[g, h] \in K$